# Dspace insert data directly into bd, but search does not work

Tags: java, postgresql, dspace

I recieved a a external java web Project , that the functionality is write directly into dspace data base (metada upload and file upload).

the information is stored into db and from dspace i can see with the new handle created and all information (Metadata and  files).

The problem is when from dspace using the search look for any metaData value the search not display any asociated result.

Dspace version 4.1 and using sorl 4.4.

Can I forced manually or via java sorl to index the new data inserted in data base.

thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it's not a good idea to write to the db directly. There are some more things to it than only the search index that isn't updated correctly. DSpace provides some better ways to import data, see [DSpace Documentation - Ingesting Content](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Ingesting+Content+and+Metadata).

As an answer to your question: If you use the standard configuration including the Discovery Module you could try to just re-index the solr index from command line:

```
[dspace]/bin/dspace index-discovery -o
```

Also see [DSpace Documentation - Discovery](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC4x/Discovery)

Comment: Finally I use the discovery Module [dspace]/bin/dspace index-discovery -o the only things is the command re-index all data and the proces take a long time but it works.